# How does ancestry path work with git log?

Tags: git

I've read the [git log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), but I still find it very difficult to understand what the `--ancestry-path` option does. I see different ways to invoke `git log`:

```
$ git log origin/master..HEAD
$ git log --ancestry-path origin/master..HEAD
```

In the first command, I get a list of commits that are on HEAD but not on `origin/master`, basically this shows me what is on my branch that isn't merged.

In the second command, I get nothing. If I change to 3 dots (`...`) it shows me *something*, but I'm not sure how to make sense of it. Basically, how is the addition of `--ancestry-path` any different? What exactly does it *simplify*?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[Matthieu Moy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36433669/1256452) is correct but may not help you very much, if you haven't been exposed to the necessary graph theory.

#### DAGs

First, let's take a quick look at **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raphs or DAGs.  A DAG is just a graph (hence the `g`), i.e., a collection of nodes and connections between them—these work like train stations on rail lines, for instance, where the stations are the nodes—that is "directed" (the `d`: trains only run one way) and have no loops in them (the `a`).

Linear chains and tree structures are valid DAGs (note: newer commits are to the right, in general, here):

```
o <- o <- o
```

or:

```
       o <- o
      /
o <- o
      \   o
       \ /
        o
         \
          o <- o
```

(imagine the diagonal connections having arrow heads so that they point up-and-left or down-and-left, as needed).

However, non-tree graphs can have nodes that merge back (these are git's merges):

```
       o <- o
      /      \
o <- o        \
      \   o    \
       \ /      \
        o        o
         \      /
          o <- o
```

or:

```
     o--o
    /    \
o--o      o--o
    \    /
     o--o
```

(I'm just compressing the notation further here, nodes still generally point leftward).

Next, git's `..` notation does not mean what most people usually first think it means.  In particular, let's take a look at this graph again, add another node, and use some single letters to mark particular nodes:

```
     o---o
    /     \
A--o       \
    \   B   \
     \ /     \
      o       C--D
       \     /
        o---o
```

And, let's do one more thing, and stop thinking about this as just `git log` but rather the more general case of "selecting revisions with ancestry".

#### Selecting revisions (commits), with ancestry

If we select revision `A`, we get just revision `A`, because it has no ancestors (nothing to the left of it).

If we select revision `B` we get this piece of the graph:

```
A--o
    \   B
     \ /
      o
```

This is because select-with-ancestry means "Take the commit I identify, and all the commits I can get to by following the arrows back out of it."  Here the result is somewhat interesting, but not *very* interesting since there are no merges and following the arrows nets us a linear chain of four commits, starting from `B` and going back to `A`.

Selecting either `C` or `D` with ancestry, though, gets us much further.  Let's see what we get with `D`:

```
     o---o
    /     \
A--o       \
    \       \
     \       \
      o       C--D
       \     /
        o---o
```

This is, in fact, everything *except* commit `B`.  Why didn't we get `B`?  Because the arrows all point leftward: we get `D`, which points to `C`, which points to two un-lettered commits; those two point left, and so on, but when we hit the node just left-and-down of `B`, we aren't allowed to go rightward, against the arrow, so we can't reach `B`.

#### Two-dot notation

Now, the two-dot notation in git is really just shorthand syntax for set subtraction.<sup>1</sup>  That is, if we write `B..D` for instance, it means: "Select `D` with ancestry, and then select `B` with ancestry, and then give me the set of commits from the `D` selection after excluding (subtracting away) all commits from the `B` selection."

Selecting `D` with ancestry gets the entire graph *except* for the `B` commit.  Subtracting away the `B` selection removes `A`, the two `o` nodes we drew earlier, and `B`.  How can we remove `B` when it's not in the set?  Easy: we just *pretend* to remove it and say we're done!  That is, set subtraction only bothers to remove things that are actually in the set.

The result for `B..D` is therefore this graph:

```
     o---o
          \
           \
            \
             \
              C--D
             /
        o---o
```

#### Three-dot notation

The three-dot notation is different.  It's more useful in a simple branch-y graph, perhaps even a straight tree.  Let's start with the tree-like graph this time and look at both two- and three-dot notation.  Here's our tree-like graph, with some single letter names for nodes put in:

```
     o--I
    /
G--H
    \   J
     \ /
      K
       \
        o--L
```

This time I've added extra letters because we'll need to talk about some of the places the commits "join up", in particular at nodes `H` and `K`.

Using two-dot notation, what do we get for `L..I`?  To find the answer, start at node `I` and work backwards.  You must always move leftward, even if you also go up or down.  These are the commits that are selected.  Then, start at node `L` and work backwards, finding the nodes to *un*-select; if you come across any earlier selected ones, toss them out.  (Making the final list is left as an exercise, though I'll put the answer in as a footnote.<sup>2</sup>)

Now let's see the three-dot notation in action.  What it does is a bit complicated, because it must find the *merge base* between two branches in the graph.  The merge base has a formal definition,<sup>3</sup> but for our purposes it's just: "The point where, when following the graph backwards, we meet up at some commit."

In this case, for instance, if we ask for `L...I` or `I...L`—both produce the same result—git finds all commits that are reachable from *either* commit, but not from *both*.  That is, it excludes the merge base and all earlier commits, but keeps the commits beyond that point.

The merge base of `L` and `I` (or `I` and `L`) is commit `H`, so we get things after `H`, but not `H` itself, and we cannot reach node `J` from either `I` or `L` since it's not in their ancestry.  Hence, the result for `I...L` or `L...I` is:

```
     o--I
 



      K
       \
        o--L
```

(Note that these histories do not join up, since we tossed out node `H`.)

#### `--ancestry-path`

Now, all these are ordinary selection operations.  None have been modified with `--ancestry-path`.  The [documentation for `git log` and `git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html)—these two are almost the same command, except for their output format—describes `--ancestry-path` this way:

> When given a range of commits to display (e.g. `commit1..commit2` or
> `commit2 ^commit1`), only display commits that exist directly on the
> ancestry chain between the `commit1` and `commit2`, i.e. commits that
> are both descendants of `commit1`, and ancestors of `commit2`.

We define *ancestors* here in terms of the commit DAG: a first commit is a *direct ancestor* of a second if the second has an arrow pointing back at the first, and an *indirect ancestor* if the second points back at the first through some chain of commits.  (For selection purposes a commit is also considered an ancestor of itself.)

*Descendants* (also sometimes called *children*) are defined similarly, but by going against the arrows in the graph.  A commit is a child (or descendant) of another commit if there's a path between them.

Note that the description of the `--ancestry-path` talks about using the two-dot notation, not the three-dot notation, probably because the implementation of the three-dot notation is a little bit weird inside.  As noted earlier, `B...D` excludes (as if with leading `^`) the *merge base* (or bases, if there is/are more than one) of the two commits, so the merge base is the one that play the "must be child-of" role.  I'll mention how `--ancestry-path` works with this, though I'm not sure how useful it is in "real world" examples.

#### Practical examples

What does this mean in practice?  Well, it depends on the arguments you give, and the actual commit DAG.  Let's look at the funky loopy graph again:

```
     o---o
    /     \
A--o       \
    \   B   \
     \ /     \
      o       C--D
       \     /
        o---o
```

Suppose we ask for `B..D` here *without* `--ancestry-path`.  This means we take commit `D` and its ancestors, but exclude `B` and its ancestors, just as we saw before.  Now let's add `--ancestry-path`.  Everything we had earlier was an ancestor of `D`, and that's still true, but this new flag says we must *also* toss out commits that are *not* children of `B`.

How many children does node `B` have?  Well, none!  So we must toss out every commit, giving us a *completely empty list*.

---

What if we ask for `B...D`, without the special `--ancestry-path` notation?  That gives us everything reachable from either `D` *or* `B`, but excludes everything reachable from both `D` *and* `B`:

```
     o---o
          \
           \
        B   \
             \
              C--D
             /
        o---o
```

This is the same as `B..D` except that we get node `B` as well.

[Note: the section below on mixing `--ancestry-path` with `B...D` was wrong for almost a year, between April 2016 and Feb 2017.  It has been fixed to note that the "must be child" part starts from the *merge base(s)*, not from the left side of the `B...D` notation.]

Suppose we add `--ancestry-path` here.  We *start* with the same graph we just got for `B...D` without `--ancestry-path`, but then *discard* items that are not children of the merge base.  The merge base is the `o` just to the left of `B`.  The top row `o` commits are not children of this node, so they are discarded.  Again, as with ancestors, we consider a node its own child, so we *would* keep this node itself—giving this partial result:

```
        B
       /
      o       C--D
       \     /
        o---o
```

But, while we are (or `--ancestry-path` is) discarding children of this merge base node, the merge base node itself, to the down-and-left of `B`, was not in the `B...D` graph in the first place.  Hence, the final result (actually tested in Git 2.10.1) is:

```
        B

              C--D
             /
        o---o
```

(Again, I'm not really sure how useful this is in practice.  The starting graph, again, is that of `B...D`: everything reachable from *either* commit, minus everything reachable from *both* commits: this works by discarding starting from every merge base, if there are two or more.  The child-of checking code also handles a list of commits.  It retains everything that *is* a child of *any* of the merge bases, if there are multiple merge bases.  See the function `limit_to_ancestry` in [`revision.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/revision.c).)

#### Thus, it depends on the graph *and* the selectors

The final action of `X..Y` or `X...Y`, with or without `--ancestry-path`, depends on the commit graph.  To predict it, you must draw the graph.  (Use `git log --graph`, perhaps with `--oneline --decorate --all`, or use a viewer that draws the graph for you.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There's an exception in `git diff`, which does its own special handling for `X..Y` and `X...Y`.  When you are not using `git diff` you should just ignore its special handling.

<sup>2</sup>We start with `I` and the `o` to its left, and also `H` and `G`.  Then we lose `H` and `G` when we work back from `L`, so the result is just `o--I`.

<sup>3</sup>The formal definition is that the merge base is the **L**owest **C**ommon **A**ncestor, or LCA, of the given nodes in the graph.  In some graphs there may be multiple LCAs; for Git, these are all merge bases, and `X...Y` will exclude all of them.

It's interesting / instructive to run `git rev-parse B...D` for the graph I drew.  These commit hashes here depend on not just the graph itself, and the commit, but also the *time stamps* at which one makes the commits, so if you build this same graph, you will get different hashes, but here are the ones I got while revising the answer to fix the description of `--ancestry-path` interacting with `B...D`:

```
$ git rev-parse B...D
3f0490d4996aecc6a17419f9cf5a4ab420c34cc2
7f0b666b4098282301a9f95e056a646483c2e5fc
^843eaf75d78520f9a569da35d4e561a036a7f107
```

but we can see that these are `D`, `B`, and the merge base, in that order, using several more commands:

```
$ git rev-parse B     # this produces the middle hash
7f0b666b4098282301a9f95e056a646483c2e5fc
```

and:

```
$ git rev-parse D     # this produces the first hash
3f0490d4996aecc6a17419f9cf5a4ab420c34cc2
```

and:

```
$ git merge-base B D  # this produces the last, negated, hash
843eaf75d78520f9a569da35d4e561a036a7f107
```

Graphs with multiple merge bases do occur, but they're somewhat harder to construct—the easy way is with "criss cross" merges, where you run `git checkout br1; git merge br2; git checkout br2; git merge br1`.  If you get this situation and run `git rev-list` you will see several negated hashes, one per merge base.  Run `git merge-base --all` and you will see the same set of merge bases.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to this so late... but this is a very good answer. It's like reading a book. Great job. I do find it difficult to imagine a use case for --ancestry-path, but at least I can see how it simplifies things now by adding 1 more rule.

Comment: @torek Amazing answer! Read and grasped in one sitting!

Comment: @EugeniuRosca I just fixed an issue with `--ancestry-path` vs symmetric difference (three-dot) notation. I'm not sure it's actually useful in practice, but since it was wrong, I thought I'd better fix it.

Comment: @torek, for extra points, the `L..I` and `I...L`, while giving the same _list_ of commits, can differentiate between those on the left side and those on the right hand side of the request. See `--left-right` option in the `git help rev-list` and `...` in `git help revisons`.

Comment: @PhilipOakley: true, but I'm not sure how you would *use* this with `--ancestry-path`. (It's definitely useful without that option.)

Comment: @torek --ancestry-path should avoid using either of the dot notations, as your example shows. In the `git help rev-list` man page, after "fifth simplification mode" it explains a real example, though unfortunately there isn't yet a `--first-parent-show` option (e.g. to go with `--merge`) to tell you where the commit was merged to mainline. (the --first-parent walk limiting is incompatible with --ancestry-path!)

Comment: @torek, oops I think I mis-understood your comment. Yes, the left and right markings are probably irrelevant for 99.7% of your discussion. It was only the line "if we ask for L...I or I...L—both produce the same result" that I was quibbling about 'sameness, as there is that little bit extra info available if needed for `--left-only` and `--right only`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The answer itself kind of got out of hand.  Part of the problem is that it discusses too much, with too many different input graphs.  The other part is that when I wrote it, I didn't realize how `--ancestry-path` and symmetric difference wind up interacting (which is rather odd).

Comment: I've read like down til the first few diagrams. I read it two times. It's not super clear when I'm reading `o <- o <- o`, which commit is the oldest and what comes after. Can you make an edit? ie it's not clear if `a <- b ` means 'b' was made off of 'a' or that 'a' is the next commit after 'b'. After multiple readings I can tell that it's 'a' is the next commit after 'b' but again not super clear for _me_

Comment: @Honey: I'll look at updating it, but in general, older commits are to the left; newer ones are to the right.

Comment: oops yes. That's what I meant. It was clear after _reading_ 'If we select revision B we get this piece of the graph' but not clear from _looking_ at the graphs

Answer (score 5):

As the documentation says, `--ancestry-path` removes commits that are not descendant of `origin/master`. If you have a local, unmerged branch, and this branch is based on a commit which is older than `origin/master`, then commits in this branch will not be shown because these commits are not descendant of `origin/master`.

Comment: So you're saying it's the inverse of `..` notation?

Comment: For some definition of "inverse" ;-). It takes all the commits in `origin/master..HEAD` and then it filters out commits that are not descendant from `origin/master`, which is more or less the inverse of the `..` notation indeed.

Comment: Matthieu, do you know off-hand if there is a way to `git rebase -i --ancestry-path`?  If not, I'll post it as a separate question.  I had exactly the situation you describe, and the normal `base..HEAD` gave me more commits in the `rebase -i` than I wanted.  I can't find an existing tool that does that (vanilla `git-rebase` doesn't), and am wondering if you are aware of one.  Thanks!

Comment: You can always specify the commits you want with e.g. `git rebase -i HEAD~3 --onto master` to rebase the last 3 commits onto master for example.

Comment: so basically it's an _intersection_ of commits in current branch with commits after origin/master. Which in this case since the branch is behind, then the intersection is empty?

Answer (score 2):

Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) illustrates how `git log --ancestry-path` works, and extends that `--ancestry-path` option with a value.

"[`git rev-list --ancestry-path=C A..B`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0b08ba7eb666803973ccbb60b8e1a4436fe494b5/Documentation/git-rev-list.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))</sup> is a natural extension of `git rev-list  A..B`;
instead of choosing a subset of `A..B` to those that have ancestry relationship with `A`, it lets a subset with ancestry relationship with *`C`*.

See [commit 1838e21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1838e21cff17f97900a4987b35ba70ca48bce4b7) (19 Aug 2022) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
See [commit 257418c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/257418c59040c13bfa839e01922e21833cda6a52), [commit 11ea33c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11ea33ce444f929908990ec24c58d848373bdda3) (19 Aug 2022) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0b08ba7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b08ba7eb666803973ccbb60b8e1a4436fe494b5), 29 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`revision`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/257418c59040c13bfa839e01922e21833cda6a52): allow --ancestry-path to take an argument
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> We have long allowed users to run e.g.
>
> ```
> git log --ancestry-path master..seen
> ```
>
> which shows all commits which satisfy all three of these criteria:
>
> - are an ancestor of `seen`
> - are not an ancestor of `master`
> - have `master` as an ancestor
>
> This commit allows another variant:
>
> ```
> git log --ancestry-path=$TOPIC master..seen
> ```
>
> which shows all commits which satisfy all of these criteria:
>
> - are an ancestor of `seen`
> - are not an ancestor of master
> - have `$TOPIC` in their ancestry-path
>
> that last bullet can be defined as commits meeting any of these criteria:
>
> - are an ancestor of `$TOPIC`
> - have `$TOPIC` as an ancestor
> - are `$TOPIC`
>
> This also allows multiple `--ancestry-path` arguments, which can be used to find commits with any of the given topics in their ancestry path.

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/257418c59040c13bfa839e01922e21833cda6a52/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L394-L399):

> ### `--ancestry-path[=<commit>]`
>
> When given a range of commits to display (e.g. '`commit1..commit2`'
> or '`commit2 {caret}commit1`'), only display commits in that range
> that are ancestors of `<commit>`, descendants of `<commit>`, or
> `<commit>` itself.
>
> If no commit is specified, use '`commit1`' (the
> excluded part of the range) as `<commit>`.
>
> Can be passed multiple times; if so, a commit is included if it is any of the commits
> given or if it is an ancestor or descendant of one of them.

> As an example use case, consider the following commit history:
>
> ```
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------
>       D---E-------F
>      /     \       \
>     B---C---G---H---I---J
>    /                     \
>   A-------K---------------L--M
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> When we want to find out what commits in `M` are contaminated with the
> bug introduced by `D` and need fixing, however, we might want to view
> only the subset of '`D..M`' that are actually descendants of `D`, i.e.
> excluding `C` and `K`.
>
> This is exactly what the `--ancestry-path`
> option does.
> Applied to the 'D..M' range, it results in:
>
> ```
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------
>       E-------F
>        \       \
>         G---H---I---J
>                  \
>               L--M
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/257418c59040c13bfa839e01922e21833cda6a52/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L608-L630):

> We can also use `--ancestry-path=D` instead of `--ancestry-path` which
> means the same thing when applied to the '`D..M`' range but is just more
> explicit.
>
> If we instead are interested in a given topic within this range, and all
> commits affected by that topic, we may only want to view the subset of
> `D..M` which contain that topic in their ancestry path.
>
> So, using
> `--ancestry-path=H D..M` for example would result in:
>
> ```
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------
> E
> \
> G---H---I---J
> \
> L--M
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Whereas `--ancestry-path=K D..M` would result in
>
> ```
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------
> K---------------L--M
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```