# filter git log --merges by commiter of the second parent

Tags: git, version-control

Giving below example of git history:

```
  .-A---M---N---O---P---Q
 /     /   /   /   /   /
I     B   C   D   E   Y
 \   /   /   /   /   /
  `-------------'   X
```

And assuming that:

- `A...Q` are all merge commits
- `A...Q` is the line with first parent for `A...Q`
- `B...Y` is the line with second parent for `A...Q`
- Commiter of `B`, `D` and `Y` is Josephine
- Commiter of `C` and `E` is Lucian

How can I list the commits in `A...Q` merging Lucian's work only?

Comment: Not sure who downvoted the question, or why, although I vaguely recall answering something similar before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with a single `git log` command.  The crucial problem is item 3:

1. fact: the top line `A---Q` are all merge commits
2. requirement: select only top-line commits ...
3. requirement: merging Lucian's work only (apparently per committer name or committer email, but we can test author instead easily enough; see below)

since this requires testing the committer of the *second parent* of each of these merges.  The tests provided by `--author=` and `--committer=` test the commit itself, i.e., if we've selected a merge in the first place, we will examine the author or committer of the merge itself.

Therefore, the solution is to use `git log`'s script-oriented sibling, `git rev-list`, in combination with a script.  There are no doubt multiple ways to write the script, but the most obvious to me is to use `git rev-list` to select all potentially-interesting merge commits first.

It's not clear to me (since this is the graph right out of the `git log` and `git rev-list` documentation) whether you mean to imply that there are only these commits, or that there might be even more merges "internally", e.g., perhaps `X` is not a single commit but rather a whole chain of commits that may contain its own branches-and-merges.  If you do want *only* top-line commits you could use `--first-parent`, or if you have an `--ancestry-path` in mind such as `--ancestry-path I..Q`, you could use that.  Add `--merges` to whatever limiting you like to get *all* the top-line merges, or perhaps all the merges:

```
git rev-list --merges Q |
```

The output from `git rev-list` will include all the merge commits, and now we write the remaining pipe, which tests each merge and discards it unless the second parent's author or committer are the one we want:

```
git rev-list --merges Q |
    while read rev; do
        p2=$(git rev-parse ${rev}^2)
        person=$(git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%cn $p2) # or %aN or %ce etc
        [ "$person" == "who we want" ] && echo $rev
    done
```

The output from this little script is the set of commits to view, so we simply pipe it to `git log --stdin --no-walk` to get the final output:

```
git rev-list --merges Q |
    while read rev; do
        p2=$(git rev-parse ${rev}^2)
        person=$(git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%cn $p2)
        [ "$person" == "who we want" ] && echo $rev
    done |
    git log --stdin --no-walk # add formatting etc as desired
```

Comment: Thanks for such a rich and detailed answer! I will give it a try in my specific use-case and let you know the results later. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Your template works fine! Another approach that glimpsed in my mind is starting with the commits authored by `"who we want"` and checking if they have a child/descendant amongst `A..Q` (or if their child is a merge authored by a specific maintainer - not really in scope of the initial question), but I guess this would be slower (depends on a given git graph). It's a pity git doesn't expose some options for such use-cases! From my side, five stars for your answer! As a complementary reading I would suggest another reply of yours http://stackoverflow.com/a/36437843/2381750