# How to get count of commits between head and a commit in history?

Tags: git

How can I get to know the number of commit before a particular commit?
For example, I have these commit hash

```
f66a9f1df6
bf211314a6
a532e51fb2
59d11f1a2b
8eed94070f
b849946aa2
f7fdee8bd3
```

`f66a9f1df6` being the head how can I know the total number of commit above `f7fdee8bd3`?
Here by counting its clear that I can get `show` last commit just by `git show HEAD^6`

I wanted to use this to review PRs with a huge number of commits like ~50 and wanted to use `git show HEAD^n` to log the changes.

Comment: do you want the number between two commits? -- also do you know about `git log -p`?

Comment: yes I do know about that @AnthonySottile , but that lists out all the commit changes rather than a particular one which will be more neat.

Comment: So the output should be six?

Comment: yeah @UnbearableLightness

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git rev-list  COMMIT_HASH.. --count` will count the number of commits between COMMIT_HASH and the current commit. If you omit `--count` you will  get a list of commit hashes. There are a number of other options available such as filtering by date, with documentation located in the man page for `git-rev-list`.

Comment: This is generally the right answer. Consider adding `--ancestry-path`, though, depending on what you mean by *between*. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36433572/1256452) for more.

Answer (score 4):

```
git log HEAD...f7fdee8bd3 --oneline | wc -l
```