# How does git log's ancestry path work with multiple negated commits?

Tags: git

The behavior of git's `--ancestry-path` option for `git log` or `git rev-list` is relatively straightforward when there is only one negated commit - that is, if you have:

```
git rev-list ^A B
# or it's shorthand form:
git rev-list A..B
```

...then the result is all commits that are descendents of A and ancestors of B (for a fuller explanation see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433572/how-does-ancestry-path-work-with-git-log)).

However, I wish to know how `--ancestry-path` behaves if you have TWO (or more) negated revisions - ie:

```
git rev-list ^C ^A B
```

(Note - I will refer to non-negated revisions, such as `B` above, as "postive" commits, and all negated revisions as "negative" commits.)

After inspecting the results in some simple test cases, the "descendents" restriction imposed by `--ancestry-path` for negative commits seemed to be OR'd / union'ed together - that is, git seemed to be doing:

- first, find all commits that are ancestors of at least one positive commit
- then, filter down to only commits that are descendents of at least one negative commit
- then, filter out commits that are ancestors of at least one negative commit

Or, in more set-like notation:

```
IntersectionOf(
    Union(ancestors(positive1), ...ancestors(positiveN))
       AND
    Union(descendents(negative1), ...descendents(negativeN))
)
- Union(ancestors(negative1), ...ancestors(negativeN))
```

However, in some more complex scenarios, this proved to incorrect - there were more commits excluded in the final result than the above logic would imply.

For example, suppose you have this full graph:

```
ancestors(MA3)

      -----MA3
     /     |  
    /      MB3
   A3     /|  
  /|    B3 |  
 / |   /|  |  
R3-+--- |  |  
|  |    |  |  
|  |  --+--MA2
|  | /  |  |  
|  |/   |  MB2
|  A2   | /|  
| /|    B2 |  
|/ |   /|  |  
R2-+--- |  |  
|  |    |  |  
|  |  --+--M1 
|  | /  |  /  
|  A1   | /   
| /     B1    
|/     /      
R1-----
```

This represents a common root branch (R), which both feature branches A and B inherit from, and A and B are in turn merged into a common merge branch (M).  ([And here's a bash script to set up a repo with this structure!](https://gist.github.com/pmolodo/3949531594fa590cb2c2bce0ee7e7230))

We wish to find:

```
--ancestry-path ^R2 ^B3 MA3
```

If we do

```
Union(descendents(R2),      Union(ancestors(R2),
      descendents(B3))            ancestors(B3))

      -----MA3                                 
     /     |                                   
    /      MB3                                 
   A3     /|                                   
  /|    B3 |                             B3    
 / |   /|  |                            /|     
R3-+--- |  |                     R3----- |     
   |    |  |                     |       |     
   |  --+--MA2                   |       |     
   | /  |  |                     |       |     
   |/   |  MB2      MINUS        |       |     
   A2   | /                      |       |     
        B2                       |       B2    
                                 |      /|     
                                 R2----- |     
                                 |       |     
                                 |       |     
                                 |       |     
                                 |       |     
                                 |       B1    
                                 |      /      
                                 R1-----
```

then we expect:

```
      -----MA3
     /     |  
    /      MB3
   A3      |  
   |       |  
   |       |  
   |       |  
   |       |  
   |  -----MA2
   | /     |  
   |/      MB2
   A2
```

However, what we actually get from

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path ^R2 ^B3 MA3 | xargs -i git tag --points-at '{}'
```

is:

```
MA3
MB3
A3
MA2
A2
```

ie:

```
      -----MA3
     /     |  
    /      MB3
   A3      |  
   |       |  
   |       |  
   |       |  
   |       |  
   |  -----MA2
   | /        
   |/         
   A2
```

...which is the same, except MB2 is excluded.

So, clearly, my guess at how `--ancestry-path` works with multiple `^` negations is wrong.  Can anyone explain the logic git actually uses, and why MB2 is excluded?

**EDIT**
So, just to visually clarify the answer from jthill below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65450624/920545), he's saying it works like this:

- First, git calculates `ancestors(MA3) - Union(ancestors(R2), ancestors(B3)` - so we end up with:

```
ancestors(MA3) - Union(ancestors(R2),
                       ancestors(B3))

      -----MA3
     /     |  
    /      MB3
   A3      |  
   |       |  
   |       |  
   |       |  
   |       |  
   |  -----MA2
   | /     |  
   |/      MB2
   A2      |  
   |       |  
   |       |  
   +       |  
   |       |  
   |  -----M1 
   | /        
   A1
```

It then tries to find all nodes along paths from `R2` or `B3` to `MA3`, USING THIS LIMITED SET OF NODES.  So, it tries to find all paths from (x) to [y]  on this graph:

```
        ----[MA3]
       /     |  
      /      MB3
     A3     /|  
     |  (B3) |  
     |       |  
     |       |  
     |       |  
     |  -----MA2
     | /     |  
     |/      MB2
     A2      |  
    /|       |  
   / |       |  
(R2) |       |  
     |       |  
     |  -----M1 
     | /        
     A1
```

...which is why we end up with the result I showed above. Thank you jthill!

Comment: How did you make your diagrams? They're fantastic.

Comment: Hah, thanks! Just sketched it out on paper, then made them manually (with some assistance from vscode's multi-line editing.)

Comment: I spent some time making the graphs for different combinations and I can't figure out why MB2 is excluded either. This might be one for the git mailing list.

Comment: That code, inside the Git revision walker, is incredibly twisty and full of passages (code paths) that are almost but not quite alike. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure#Maze_of_twisty_little_passages) The behavior here could just be a bug. It's not clear to me what *should* happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MB2` is on an ancestry path to `R2`, as its name suggests, but that ancestry path steps outside the bounds you set when you excluded ancestors of `B3` from your walk.

Git's doing what you asked for: take `MA3` and all its ancestors, exclude `B3` and `R2` and all *their* ancestors, and *then* try to trace an ancestry path to the excluded tips.

The effect that gets often produces the same results as all-descendants-minus-all-ancestors tracing, but you've found a case where the difference matters. Git traces ancestry, not descent.

Comment: I see where you're going with the ancestry vs descent, but I'm still trying to puzzle out the specifics in this example. Could you spell it out?

Comment: @Schwern I think it boils down to sequencing: OP's expecting the pathfinding to be done before the ancestor culling, where Git really does the ancestor culling before the  pathfinding.  The tips and exclusions set the bounds within which it hunts for an ancestry path. Mark all boundary ancestors as out-of-bounds first or wind up uselessly retracing all of history repeatedly.

Comment: Ahhh... I see. So because `B2` is first excluded by `^B3`, git can't then trace a route back from `MA3` to `R2` that goes through `MB2`. So it doesn't show up in the final result...